# Replacing NA from a specific column with latest non-NA value from that row in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse, tidyr

I have a large data frame that looks like this

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(fruits=c("apple","banana","ananas"),
             col1=c(4,NA,NA),
             col2=c(5,NA,10),
             col3=c(10,100,5),
             col4=c(20,4,1))
df
#> # A tibble: 3 × 5
#>   fruits  col1  col2  col3  col4
#>   <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 apple      4     5    10    20
#> 2 banana    NA    NA   100     4
#> 3 ananas    NA    10     5     1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

When there is an NA value only of the col1, I want to fill the NA with the last non-NA value of the row and return the value to NA.

I want my data to look like this.

```
#> # A tibble: 3 × 5
#>   fruits  col1  col2  col3  col4
#>   <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 apple      4     5    10    20
#> 2 banana    100   NA    NA     4
#> 3 ananas    10    NA     5     1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is a large data.frame, it may be more efficient to use vectorized solution instead of looping over rows.  Get the logical index of elements in 'col1' that are `NA` ('i1'), use `max.col` to return the column index of `first` non-NA element from columns 3 to 5 ('j1'), create a row/column index matrix (`m1`) with `cbind`, assign the 'col1' where there are missing values with the elements extracted from 3 to 5 columns using 'm1' and assign those elements to `NA`

```
df1 <- as.data.frame(df)
i1 <- is.na(df1$col1)
j1 <- max.col(!is.na(df1[3:5]), "first")
m1 <- cbind(which(i1), j1[i1])
df1$col1[i1] <- df1[3:5][m1]
df1[3:5][m1] <- NA
```

-output

```
> df1
  fruits col1 col2 col3 col4
1  apple    4    5   10   20
2 banana  100   NA   NA    4
3 ananas   10   NA    5    1
```